# Attribute error is displayed while webscraping using selenium, python. Request to help me out in this case

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3360/3649629551.py in <module>
     19 book_length=[]
     20 
---> 21 book_title.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//h3[contains(@class,"bc-heading")]').text)
     22 book_author.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class,"authorLabel")]').text)
     23 book_length.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class,"runtimeLabel")]').text)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website='https://www.audible.com/search'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()

container=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'adbl-impression-container')
product=container.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li\[contains(@class, "productListItem")\]')

book_title=\[\]
book_author=\[\]
book_length=\[\]

book_title.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//h3\[contains(@class,"bc-  heading")\]').text)
book_author.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li\[contains(@class,"authorLabel")\]').text)
book_length.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li\[contains(@class,"runtimeLabel")\]').text)

driver.quit()

df=pd.DataFrame({'Title':book_title,'Author':book_author, 'Runtime':book_length})
df.to_csv('audible_data.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: `product=container.find_elements` returns a list. you might have forgotten to loop over it, or did you want `product=container.find_element`?

Comment: Yeah..I had forgotten to loop the contents. But even after looping I am getting the empty DataFrame. Not sure ..why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product` variable is a list.

You can't execute `find_element` from list of items.

Instead of this, you should loop through it and call `find_element` for each item.

```py
products = container.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class, "productListItem")]')

book_title=[]
book_author=[]
book_length=[]
for product in products:
    book_title.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//h3[contains(@class,"bc-heading")]').text)
    book_author.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class,"authorLabel")]').text)
    book_length.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//li[contains(@class,"runtimeLabel")]').text)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I added the loop now, but its showing the result as displayed below:  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Author, Runtime]
Index: []

Comment: I have got the result. Thanks for the help.:)

Comment: Can you please set this answer as "correct" if it resolves your issue? :)